# WebStorm - Setting up debug environment

Tags: node.js, apache, debugging, webstorm

I am new to WebStorm/node.js and need help/suggestion setting up a debug environment for my current project.

1) Currently we are using Apache web server, where the document root folder is configured/pointed to the build folder after running `npm run build`.

2) We have set rules (in Apache, `virtualhosts.conf`) to redirect the rest api calls to another server to get the json response, like:

- for URL: `/abc/restapi/{param1}/*`
- redirect to : `http://"servername"/abc/restapi/{param1}/*`

Plus add some additional request headers.

How can we do the above configuration in WebStorm so that I can actually put a breakpoint and debug in the IDE itself (server can be anything)?

Comment: why can't you use Apache server for debugging in webStorm?

Comment: I can't find plugin for Apache...i searched in the repository as well..

Comment: don't understand what you mean to say... You don't need any special plugins to be able to host your application on Apache. And URL re-writing is handled by the web server, not by the IDE